# Recommended way to check if a file is compressed /zipped

Tags: go

I am trying to check if an uploaded file ( no file extension) is compressed/ zipped.
I searched through the fileinfo, fileheader etc but haven't found a way to do this. May be the magic number?
Thanks

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/

Comment: With a little googling I was able to find this: https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-compressed-either-gzip-or-zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick-and-easy built-in way is with `http.DetectContentType()`. It does much more than just gzip/zip, but it's very fast because it doesn't check for too many things. If you want to check for a smaller set, and skip testing a string, check the source code in src/net/http/sniff.go and pull out the tests you want.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.